# Google / Gmail: How to avoid the bother of always generating apps passwords?

Tags: passwords, gmail

I have several gmail accounts with which I have no problem, but I have one non-gmail address that I check on Chrome using the gmail interface and everything Gmail (SMTP, IMAP…) (I don't even know how that's possible, but I do it). I made an account for this address on my Mail application (Mail 8.1 with Mac OS 10.10.1).

The point is: everytime I re-open Mail, I have to generate from Chrome a new "app password" (16 digit random number) and paste it into Mail. I save the new password everytime, but everytime I must generate a new one. How do I avoid this super boring step? I don't want either to enable 2-step verification for this. Thank you so much if you can help, I'm so tired with this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok, sorry for that